# Android Build failed - Ionic / Cordova - Unable to add asset file - file already in archive

Tags: android, cordova

Got this error:

```
Unable to add '/Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/lib/angular-localization/angular-localization.min.js.gz': file already in archive (try '-u'?)
ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging '/Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_'
ERROR: packaging of '/Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_' failed
:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/MRW/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/MRW/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar -M /Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.ionicframework.gtrackerde947201 -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
          Unable to add '/Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/lib/angular-localization/angular-localization.min.js.gz': file already in archive (try '-u'?)
    ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging '/Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_'
    ERROR: packaging of '/Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_' failed


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 19.601 secs

/Users/MRW/Desktop/Work/niv/extern/mobile-app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
```

Can someone please help me? i tried:

- reinstall android sdk
- install it with android studio
- reinstall cordova
- reinstall ionic
- clear platform folder of project

:( i cant find an answer with google...

Answer (score 5):

You should not remove your platform folder. Problem found and it is www/lib/ directory of your project.

Some packages provided by npm, bower and another managers, contains both version for some files - original and gzipped.

In your output log i see problem assigned with www/lib/angular-localization/angular-localization.min.js.gz

Check this file and you'll find out angular-localization.min.js (without .gz extension) amy be.

For example my recent problem with www/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz.

Solution is very simple - remove all .gz files from www subdirectory of your project and run build.

```
find www/lib -type f -name "*.gz" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: I know one is not supposed to add "Thank you" answers - but Thank you, thank you, thank you ... this was confusing the hell out of me

Comment: Pretty good one line solution to the general problem.  Why does the build puke on the existing .gz, though?  This is an annoying error because the .gz files are being pulled directly from `bower` - I should not have to tweak my bower directories just to build my project...